Is it possible for a query to return a partial field value?
The source issue: An apex process querying a long text field, run JSON.deserializeUntyped and got the error:
"Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value at [line:1, column:511]"
Yet, the issue was not reproduced for the same record where it happened and according to every check I made, the value is a valid JSON.
+This was a single error while we have thousands daily transactions that run similar process.
However, I do know, that there might be other processes running (possible in parallel and might be asynchrony) that will update the field value - add or remove values ​​from the JSON, but at the end any process should save it as a valid JSON.
So out of other ideas, I thought that maybe in a certain cases it can happen that querying the field might return it in an intermediate state (other process start update it but didn't yet complete).
Is that possible? Anyone encounter such case?
Update
I opened here other question, because couldn't find this earlier, maybe can combine them later.
Still not sure how, by was able to repreduce it and it does seems that somehow the query return partial data (255 characters)
JSON Value Become Invalid (cut to 255 characeters)

I'd start by adding in some error handling to give you the bad JSON value if it happens again. It sounds like some process is incorrectly modifying the JSON, I'd guess involving an unescaped backslash, leading to the closing quote being escaped. There shouldn't be a way that you're getting a partial value in a mid-save state or anything.

thanks. I checked in the direction and continue to check, but it doesn't seem to be the problem.
Each process deserializes the value before making changes, so if any process would save it as invalid JSON, then it will stay in that invalid state.
The fact is that right now the value is certainly valid JSON.

I've only seen this error when the JSON is, in fact, invalid.  I would paste the JSON as a single line into a text editor and locate column 511. The error will be "near" that column. I seriously doubt that it is a SOQL issue, especially at character 511

@cropredy Tried it, but the JSON is valid. I did examine column 511 idea. There is no error there, however this leads me to the potential idea that I'm not getting the full value.
If I truncate only 255 characters from the long text, then I would receive exactly this error, but I don't see any reason to get only 255 characters and I cannot reproduce it... (and no it is not a metadata, it's a custom object)

Grasping at straws here -- any chance that the JSON has UTF-8 characters that look like blanks (or double quotes) to you but are really some of the other UTF-8 characters for blanks or double quotes?

@cropredy The JSON currently is valid. I can programmatically run the code section that failed with the same record and it's fine, which seems to me leave 2 options: either other pre-process modify the field at the same transaction but eventually failed to store the change due to the parsing error, or for mysterious reason the failed process query the field and find only 255 chars.
I guess for you the first option is more likely, but I just cannot find such potential process + the failed process is wrapped with try-catch so previous changes in the same transaction should be kept...

well, you could brute force and insert observations of the record in question throughout the process steps - each checking to see if the JSON is still valid. Why are you assuming only 255 chars were fetched? Is it because it is 50% of 511 (almost)?

Yes, I will probably need to add more/better debugging. If I cut only 255 chars in a script, then I do get the exact same error: JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonValue.left(255))
